# RGB Color Quantization from 8bit to 6bit

Tags: java, image, rgb, quantization, 24-bit

I want to quantize RGB Color from 8 bit to 6 bit. I wrote java code as following:

```
int ind = 0;
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){    
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){ 
        byte a = 0;
        byte r = bytes[ind];
        byte g = bytes[ind+height*width];
        byte b = bytes[ind+height*width*2]; 

        int pix = 0xff000000 | ((r & 0xff) << 16) | ((g & 0xff) << 8) | (b & 0xff);
        img.setRGB(x,y,pix);
        ind++;
    }
}
```

Then, I changed:

```
int pix = 0xff000000 | ((r & 0xff) << 16) | ((g & 0xff) << 8) | (b & 0xff);
```

To:

```
int pix = 0xff000000 | ((r & 0xff) << 12) | ((g & 0xff) << 6) | (b & 0xff);
```

cause I think it means 6 bits per pixel per channel, I don't know my understanding is right or wrong, and the output image is really weird. I hope someone can help me to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues at play here:

1. Whether you are visiting the R,G,B components correctly, and
2. Whether you are combining the components correctly.

Your visiting code is kind of weird, so I cannot vouch for it, but this should be easy to fix: does your code work for making your image grayscale?  If not, then start by fixing that.

Now, your code for converting 8-bit channels to 6-bit channels does not look correct.  You are ANDing byte values with 0xff, which is pointless, and then you are failing to shrink these values to 6-bit before ORing them together. Shrinking to 6 bits is done by shifting right by 2. So, I think you need something like this:

```
r >>= 2;
g >>= 2;
b >>= 2;
int pix = (r << 12) | (g << 6) | b;
```